# Installation of Ubuntu server 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I have installed ubuntu server 13.04
After installation when I enter the username and the password, nothing happens, still the black screen shows.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server doesn't come with a graphical environment. If you want to install one, you can install one with one of these commands depending of the flavour that you want (I ordered them by own criteria for a server, being the first the one with less resources use)

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```